# How to convert text to phpbb hash?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, phpbb3

I am trying to convert a test password (testing4) into a phpbb3 hash. This is the code I have tried:

```
<?php
/** 
*
* @package phpBB3
* @version $Id: v3_dbal.xml 44 2007-07-25 11:06:55Z smithy_dll $
* @copyright (c) 2005 phpBB Group 
* @license http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License 
*
*/

/**
* @ignore
*/
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
include ("functions_phpbb.php");

$data['new_password'] = "testing4";

$user_row = array(
    'user_password' => phpbb_hash($data['new_password'])
    );

$hash = $user_row['user_password'];

echo $hash;
?>
```

and this doesn't work either:

```
$pass = "testing4";
$hash = phpbb_hash($pass);
```

Both times I recieve the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function sql_escape() on a non-object in /home/a8544020/public_html/Pass/functions_phpbb.php on line 149
```

I have tried it on 2 different hosts without any luck. Otherwise is there an online service that simply converts text to the hash?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your `functions_phpbb.php` file is a copy of the `includes/functions.php` file of the phpBB3 package.

Now, the reason you are getting this error is because the `phpbb_hash` function uses the phpBB `unique_id` function for entropy, which depends on a database connection (to change and persist the entropy on every request).

There's two ways to fix this.

a) include phpBB's `common.php`, which will bootstrap your code for phpBB (including db connection, error handlers, etc).

b) phpBB3 uses [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for hashing. I suggest you simply download the standalone phpass package and use that to generate the hash.

Little caveat: phpBB3 changes the hash identifier from '$P$' to '$H$' (don't ask me why), so you will have to change this line:

```
$output = '$P$';
```

to:

```
$output = '$H$';
```

Since option a) adds quite some overhead, and you are probably only wanting to use the hashing functions, I'd suggest option b).

Comment: As a side note, a change has been merged into phpBB that will make 'P' work as well, this will be present in phpBB 3.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the other way. I have used the library from: http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ To make it working, you must change first 3 characters of generated HASH:

```
$P$
```

to

```
$H$
```

used in phpbb

Answer (score -1):

I wonder why they run a password hash through a SQL escaping function.. but you could simply try defining that function as a dummy:

```
function sql_escape($str) { return $str; }
```